# check if value of key is equal to certain number in an array, php

Tags: php, arrays

I wonder what is the best approach to this; basically I have this array with n keys values

```
 Array[
   'n1' => 0,
   'n2' => 1,
   'n3' => 0
]
```

I just need to check the array and return true is at least 1 value is greater than 0, and false if all values are equal to 0.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$greaterThanZero = array_filter($array, function ($v) { return $v >= 0; });
return count($greaterThanZero) >= 1;
```